# Pandas Code for Unstacking Data with Variable Amount of Data Per Column, Identified by IDs

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, dataset

I want to unstack data that looks something like this using Pandas:

```
    customer_ids | money spent
    ---------------------------
    00001        | 1000
    00001        | 1344
    00001        | 1249
    00002        | 2345
    00003        | 1234
    00003        | 1345
```

In other words, there are variable amounts of data ("visits") per customer, and the only way to tell how many each customer has is by seeing when the customer ID Changes. I would like the data to look like this:

```
    00001 | 1000 | 1344 | 1249
    00002 | 2345
    00003 | 1234 | 1345
```

But I am not sure how to do this. If it is possible using some other library than Pandas, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: See #10 in the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

While unstacking (long to wide conversion) you need to add a `visit` column. Each unique value in `visit` would be a new column in the desired wide dataframe.

`df['visit'] = df.groupby('customer_ids').cumcount() + 1`

```
  customer_ids  money_spent  visit
0        00001         1000      1
1        00001         1344      2
2        00001         1249      3
3        00002         2345      1
4        00003         1234      1
5        00003         1345      2
```

Now you can unstack to get the desired output

`df_unstacked = df.set_index(['customer_ids', 'visit']).unstack('visit').reset_index()`

This produces

```
      customer_ids money_spent                
visit                        1       2       3
0            00001      1000.0  1344.0  1249.0
1            00002      2345.0     NaN     NaN
2            00003      1234.0  1345.0     NaN
```